# Cast a string column to int in power BI

Tags: casting, powerbi

I have a table on power bi which have counter column:

[image]

Over this column I have to make some sums, which I'm trying as follow:

```
sum(my_table[contador])
```

But I get an error that sum operator does not allow string values. Hence I tried to cast it this way:

sum(INT(my_table[contador]))

But now I get an error that SUM only acepts columns as arguments. 
How can I cast each value keeping the column?

EDIT:

I have also tried to use the query editor, but it seems this solution is not compatible with DirectQuery Mode

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to cast the column type to Whole Number in the Query Editor when you are loading the data:
[image]

Or you can assign a new type to the column after loading the data in the Modeling tab:
[image]

Will this be ok for you? Or for some reason you need the column to be Text?

Comment: I tried that as well, but is not working in my case, I have updated the question with the error I got. Is it possible to do it using DAX on the main screen?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez and can you then introduce a New Column into the table within Power BI as Contador_Int = VALUE(my_table[contador]) and use it for calculation?

Comment: Yes that made it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the column converted, you can use an iterator sum instead to allow the use of `VALUE`.

```
SUMX(my_table, VALUE(my_table[contador]))
```